# I want create some hanging shelves using zinc E-Z Drywall Anchors & Sisal rope. How much weight could this method bear?

Tags: drywall, walls, drywall-anchor

I recently bought a projector and am looking to build a shelf for it to sit on. I rent, so I really don't want to do anything with the ceiling. The configuration I'm currently using is just a standard bookshelf, but the thing is there is a window directly opposite my living room wall, so the projector is off-center. What I'd like to do, rather than placing the entire bookshelf in front of the window, is to place the anchors above the window, attach the sisal rope to those anchors, & then wrap the rope around a plank of wood. My projector weighs 5.5 pounds. Is this a decent set up? Is there a better method? I really don't want it falling, so if there's no way to be certain it'll be stable, what should I do instead?

Comment: Sisal rope, drywall anchors and an expensive projector don't sound like a recipe for happiness.   Why don't you just want to put a few small screw holes in the ceiling?  It should patch as easy as the wall.

Comment: There are different sizes the small ones are rated 25 lb and the big ones are rated at 50lb I have never had any problem with them coming out and prior to selling my rental I requested these be used as they are much easier to patch than molly bolts. I use them and never had one pull out

Comment: Sisal rope isn't all that robust; you should really consider using something stronger (e.g. nylon).

Answer (score 1):

There are ceiling mounts available for most projectors that let you attach right to the ceiling, that might be easier.

However, there is an adjustment that lets you use most projectors at an oblique angle to the wall, look for a "keystoning" adjustment in your projector's manual.  This would allow you to get a perfect rectangular image with the projector in it's current spot.

Comment: Thank you for this! I will definitely try this as soon as I get home from work. This may be the perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little wacky, but it only "damages" the bookshelf. If the bookshelf is already at the window edge, then just screw a longer board to the top of the bookshelf to seat the projector where you want it laterally. If you don't want it that high you can use shelf brackets on the side of the bookshelf to make a side shelf at whatever height you want.

Comment: I really like this solution! Not too worried about the bookshelf considering it was $30. Will look into this, thank you :)